# MSBuild property to allow for column type update?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

Does there exist a MSBuild property that allows for in-place column type update? My team would like our MSBuild to work that way rather than dropping the table and recreating the updated version.

We're ok with data loss.

--Sarah

Comment: Before I edit, what do you believe this question has to do with `sql-server` or `ssis`?

Comment: @TabAlleman nothing. my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Trying /p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=False as per reading about this here:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139478/how-to-prevent-ssdt-publishing-from-dropping-columns